# How to connect with multiple databases with one entity framework dynamically.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

This is my MVC project.I'm using entity framework 5. I have one main client database script.With that i can create many client databases with just the database name as different.Now I have an entity framework model for that client databases.With one entity framework i need to connect with different databases dynamically.i'll get the database name from one textbox.I know its about to get the connection string from web.config and changing the database name.But i could not find a solution like that.I tried with "SqlConnectionStringBuilder" too.I should use only one connection string in the web.config and that for the main client database.

Here is my web.config connection string

```
    <add name="SBAClientEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ClientModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ClientModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ClientModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=USER-PC\SQL2012SERVER1;initial catalog=SBAClient;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=sa12345;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Here is my entity model Context class

```
 public partial class SBAClientEntities : DbContext
{
    public SBAClientEntities()
        : base("name=SBAClientEntities")
    {
    }
    public SBAClientEntities(string databaseName)
        : base("name=SBAClientEntities")
    {
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<CM_Customer_UISetings> CM_Customer_UISetings { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code to connect with database in repository

```
 using (SBAClientEntities db1 = new SBAClientEntities(databaseName))
        {
            CusFontViewModel obj = new CusFontViewModel();

            var result = from c in db1.CM_Customer_UISetings
                         select c;
            obj.itemList = result.ToList();
            return obj;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SBAClientEntities dbWILLBECHANGED =  new  SBAClientEntities();
dbWILLBECHANGED.Database.Connection.Open();
dbWILLBECHANGED.Database.Connection.ChangeDatabase(DatabaseNEWName);
```